# Rearranging bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to rearranging the columns on my bootstrap site. At the moment I have four images like this:

[image: Example 1]

And when the screen size goes below 768px (more or less) I would like then to be rearranged to something like this:

[image: Example 2]

I thought about using bootstraps push pull but apparently, it´s no longer an option on bootstrap 4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!--top photos -->
<div class="row" id="top_photos_div">                                  
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="photos/top_photos/busy_bee.JPG" class="img-full-width_height" alt="bee" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="photos/top_photos/midsummer_skies.JPG" class="img-full-width_height" alt="midsummer sunset" />
    </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="photos/top_photos/swans.jpg" class="img-full-width_height" alt="swans" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="photos/top_photos/wood.jpg" class="img-full-width_height" alt="a forest" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your screenshots, you don't need to change the order of images when going through a breakpoint.

So you can just replace all `col-sm-3` classes by `col-6 col-md-3`. Then on a narrow screen you will see your images as 2 rows by 2 columns. And when the width of the screen increases to 768 pixels or more, all 4 images will again fit into one row.

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#grid-options for details.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <!--top photos -->
    <div class="row" id="top_photos_div">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
            <img class="img-full-width_height" src="photos/top_photos/busy_bee.JPG" alt="bee">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
            <img class="img-full-width_height" src="photos/top_photos/midsummer_skies.JPG" alt="midsummer sunset">
        </div> 
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
            <img class="img-full-width_height" src="photos/top_photos/swans.jpg" alt="swans">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
            <img class="img-full-width_height" src="photos/top_photos/wood.jpg" alt="a forest">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following:

```
<div class="row" id="top_photos_div">
    <!--top photos -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="~/photos/top_photos/busy_bee.JPG" class="img-full-width_height" alt="bee" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="~/photos/top_photos/midsummer_skies.JPG" class="img-full-width_height" alt="midsmmer sunset" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="~/photos/top_photos/swans.jpg" class="img-full-width_height" alt="swams" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="~/photos/top_photos/wood.jpg" class="img-full-width_height" alt="a forrest" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the css I was using for `img-full-width_height` just so you know what I was using.

```
<style>
    .img-full-width_height {
        height: 170px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
```

Basically, instead of the main `row` having just one column for all of the photos, you have two columns. Setting both columns to use class `col-md-6`.